# Size of the file via ftp url using python

Tags: python, python-2.7, ftp

I've got a ftp url like `ftp://xyz/file.csv` and I need to get the size of the file before downloading it.

I tried using the urllib2,

```
>>> f = urllib2.urlopen("ftp://xyz/file.csv")
>>> f.info().getheader('Content-Length')
>>>
```

But it returns nothing, maybe because not all url(s) have a content-length header. Hence, this technique fails. Is there any other way to fetch the size information of the file without actually reading it in Python?

Python version is - **2.6.6**

Answer (score 0):

use [ftplib](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ftplib.html) by python for retrieving files over FTP protocol.

```
from ftplib import FTP
ftp = FTP('ftp.univie.ac.at')
ftp.login()
print ftp.size('applications/vim/runtime/dos/syntax/abc.vim')
```

ftp.size() returns file size in bytes. in above example comlete file path is 'ftp://ftp.univie.ac.at/applications/vim/runtime/dos/syntax/abc.vim'